# Updating a vector using a while loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop

I got the following dataframe called nodes_df:

```
    x   y node_demand
1   2  62           3
2  80  25          14
3  36  88           1
4  57  23          14
5  33  17          19
6  76  43           2
7  77  85          14
8  94   6           6
10 59  72           6
 .  .   .           .
 .  .   .           .
 .  .   .           .
 .  .   .           .
45 60  84           8
46 35 100           5
47 38   2           1
48  9   9           7
50  1  58           2
```

I have to split this `dataframe` between hubs and clients.

```
hubs <- nodes_df[keep <- sample(1:total_nodes, requested_hubs, replace = FALSE),]
client_nodes <- nodes_df[-keep, ]
```

I need to randomly select 1 row at a time from `clients_nodes` and calculate the total node_demand, I need to keep adding rows until `random_clients$node_demand` exceedes 120.

`random_clients <- client_nodes[sample(nrow(client_nodes), size = 1, replace = FALSE),]`

I created the following variables and while loop

```
node_demand <- c(0)
    cumulative_demand <- cumsum(node_demand)
    client_nodes <- nodes_df[-keep, ]
    last_node <- cumsum(cumulative_demand) >= max_supply_capacity
    condition = TRUE
    while(condition){
    random_clients <- client_nodes[sample(nrow(client_nodes), size = 1, replace = FALSE),]
    node_demand <- c(node_demand,random_clients$node_demand)
    cumulative_demand <- cumsum(node_demand)
    if(cumulative_demand <= max_supply_capacity){
      condition == FALSE
    }
    }
```

The loop doesn't stop and I get the following return value:

```
    cumulative_demand
   [1]    0   14   20   26   27   35   49   50   68   79   97  100  101  104  109  118
  [17]  119  137  150  164  178  185  188  191  208  209  219  222  227  246  252  272 (it carries on and on)
```

I am not sure why the loop doesn't stop despite the condition `cumulative_demand <= max_supply_capacity` being met.

Anybody could show me how to fix it?

**I managed to fix it :). 
I had to use `ifelse()` so R could evaluate the condition of a vector. The normal `if()` statement wouldn't work in this case**

```
while(TRUE){
random_clients <- client_nodes[sample(nrow(client_nodes), size = 1, replace = FALSE),]
node_demand <- c(node_demand,random_clients$node_demand)
cumulative_demand <- cumsum(node_demand)
last_node <- (cumulative_demand <= max_supply_capacity)
ifelse(last_node == FALSE,break,next)

}
```

Comment: The while loop runs when the condition is TRUE

Comment: Thanks! I still haven't managed the loop to break after the logical condition is met.

Comment: `condition == FALSE` looks like you are trying to compare something instead of `condition = FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use and ifelse() instead of an if() statement as shown in the problem description.